# No such element exception, dubble line Scanner

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to add two lines from `tableLineScanner`, which get's it's lines from a `Scanner` called `tableScanner`.

Anyhow, I get these errors

```
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at Database.main(Database.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

But as in the code bellow, I can't understand why I get this error. Since I check if their is two lines available and there by not engage.

```
if((tableLineScanner.hasNextLine()&&(tableLineScanner.hasNextLine()))){  //Checks if it exists two available lines.
  fieldInput = (tableLineScanner.next() + " " + (tableLineScanner.next().replaceAll("[()]", ""))+",");
  tableFields.add(fieldInput);
  System.out.println("ADDING: " + fieldInput + " to tableField array list");
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: You can't call `hasNextLine()` twice and expect it to have two lines available. You'll have to call `next()` (or better, `nextLine()`) and then `hasNextLine()` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Scanner#hasNextLine()` just tells you if there is one more line available. If you call it twice, it will still just tell you, if there is ONE more line available. You can call it `n` times, but it will just tell you about the next line.

Call `Scanner#nextLine()` and then you can test again if there is another line available.

Always do it that way:

1. Test if more data is available
2. Read data
3. Test if more data is available
4. ...

---

```
if (tableLineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String firstLine = tableLineScanner.nextLine();

    if (tableLineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String secondLine = tableLineScanner.nextLine().replaceAll(...);

        tableFields.add(firstLine + secondLine);
    } else {
        // No-second-line error handling goes here
    }
} else {
    // No-first-line error handling goes here (if any)
}
```

Comment: Since I am quite the beginner when it comes to programming, I am not sure how this is going to be implemented. ( I am tired as hell, and don't really have any energy, I am soon going to bed)

if(tableLineScanner.next(2)){? or something like that?